# Quiz point variable python

Tags: python, variables

So I'm currently creating a basic python code as I am kinda new. Here is my code:

```
import sys

points = 0
Start=input("Press Enter to start the quiz or type quit to end exit: ")
if Start == "quit":
    sys.exit()
elif Start == "":\
    print("Hello, Welcome to the maths quiz!" + "\n" "You will be asked 10 questions in total. - For every correct answer you will gain one point" + "\n" "For every wrong answer, one point wil be deducted from your total points" + "\n")
else:
    sys.exit()

firstq=input("First answer: What is 10+10?: ")
if firstq == "20":
    points = points + 1
    print("Correct answer! Total points:" + str(points))
else:
    points = points - 1
    print("Wrong answer! Total points:" + str(points))
```

If the answer was wrong on the first question. Points would be -1. However, is there a way that it doens't make points a negative but rather stay at 0?
Would I have to create another if statement which would like look this:

```
firstq=input("First answer: What is 10+10?: ")
if firstq == "20":
    points = points + 1
    print("Correct answer! Total points:" + str(points))
else:
    if points > 0:
        points = points - 1
    print("Wrong answer! Total points:" + str(points))
```

Or is there a better way of doing this because I would have to add this for every question:

```
if points > 0:
        points = points - 1
```

Comment: just use `max` for example `max(0, points - 1)`

Answer (score 2):

Probably the most straightforward way is the following:

```
points = max(points - 1, 0)
```

so points wouldn't be decremented when the next value is less than 0.

A couple of other options:

1) Ternary if

```
points = points - 1 if points > 0 else 0
```

2) Custom class and magic method in case if you need more complex scoring logic in other places.

class Score:
    def **init**(self, start_val=0):
        self.points = start_val

```
def increment(self, val=1):
    self.points += val

def decrement(self, val=1):
    self.points -= val
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function for that. Write above the other code

```
def calculate_points(new_points, current_points):
    current_points += new_points
    if current_points < 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return current_points
```

call it in your code:

```
# instead of points = points + 1
points = calculate_points(1, points)

# instead of points = points -1 . Your points will never be under 0
points = calculate_points(-1, points)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the truthy value and only assign `points - 1` to `points` when it is truthy, which in your case happens only when `points` is greater than `0`:

```
points = points and points - 1
```